# Trying to return ALL objects with key values that match these values

Tags: javascript, lodash

So lets say I have some JSON:

```
{
    "users": [{
        "name": "bob",
        "age": 16,
        "likes": ["cats", "kayaking", "knitting"]
    }, {
        "name": "kyle",
        "age": 19,
        "likes": ["dogs", "soccer", "baseball"]
    }, {
        "name": "mike",
        "age": 18,
        "likes": ["cats", "cars", "kayaking"]
    }]
}
```

and I want to go through that and return all user objects with the likes that include "cats" and "kayaking". I'm using lodash and there doesn't seem to be a lodash method to do that. I only see _.findKey and _.includes. Is there a method or group of methods that I can use that'll do this or am I better off just using vanilla javascript?

Comment: You can use [`_.filter`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) with lodash. You can also just do it with vanilla JavaScript using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`_.filter()`](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
var output = _.filter(input.users, function(item) {
    return _.includes(item.likes, 'cats')
        && _.includes(item.likes, 'kayaking');
});
```

It **filters the array using the filter function you specify**. If this filter function returns `true` for a given item of the array, this item will be included in the resulting array.

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Vanilla JS:

---

You can use `indexOf` along with a comparator array for comparison.

Using this comparator array, you can filter the results to return only the objects that match the criteria.

Additionally use a `reduce` method to return true or false depending on whether or not *one* of the strings in the array matches your comparator array.

```
var comparator = ['dogs', 'baseball'];

var dogsAndBaseball = obj.users.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.reduce(function(acc, cur) {
    return acc || comparator.indexOf(cur) > -1;
  }, false);
});
```

This will return

```
[{
    "name": "kyle",
    "age": 19,
    "likes": ["dogs", "soccer", "baseball"]
}]
```